# Integrate .net core with regular .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a library that only exists in .net regular framework.

Now I´m developing a asp.net core project and need some features from this library.

Is it possible to integrate it with .net core project?

Comment: @Nikki9696, it is the CloudinaryDotNet library.

Comment: Are you saying that when you include that dll and target core, it won't compile? That's a 3rd party dll, it's not technically part of regular .net framework. I found a thread about windows phone calling it, what did you need from it?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer to this is that you wont be able to use the Net Framework DLL in your Net Core project. This is because of the disparity between API's available in Framework v Core. The Net Standard was introduced to try to bring some clarity and parity to the whole situation; but the answer really lies in a few different things. The version of Net Framework that the DLL requires, and the Net Core version you are running. This tool might help you to see the problems your DLL will cause trying to use it. You might be in the situation where you either cant use it, or you need to try and port it to a newer version of Net Framework that matches up with Net Core (via the Net Standard).

Its all a little confusing I'm afraid and theres no easy answer other than, read up on Net Standard, and compare the dependencies between your DLL and Net Core